# Edit a View (TextView / ImageView) inside a layout used in <include> tag using custom attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-include

I'm new to Android Development.
Is it possible to change a View inside an included layout using custom attribute?

I mean like this:

This is `my_layout` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userImage"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="..." />
    <!-- this src attribute can be overrided using my own attribute in the iclude tage -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="..." />
    <!-- this text attribute can be overrided using my own attribute in the iclude tage -->
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how I want to include `my_layout` to the activity layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_layout" userName="@string/userName1" userImage="@drawable/userImage1"/>
```

`userName` and `userImage` override the value of `android:text` and `android:src` attribute.

I have read about [**Data Binding**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) but what I mean here is not using any Java class. I just need to define a variable into data tag in `my_layout` with `type` value referenced to `@string/` or `@drawable/` to get a text or picture.

Is it possible?

Comment: Careful it might be XY problem. Why do you need to ad this `custom:userName`

Comment: @Jacky The purpose is to change some Views inside the `my_layout` layout, maybe TextView or ImageView. The `custom:` namespace is just determine that what I need is an custom attribute I define myself.

Comment: @Jacky I have updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your description, you want to post `userName1` and `userImage1` to the View in `my_layout`. You can not make it. And the way you use the custom view is wrong. The tag 'include' is also not custom tag.

You can use custom attribute follow this sample:

```
<com.amscf.view.InviteItemView
    android:id="@+id/invite_item_instagram"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_color"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    app:appicon="@drawable/icon_app_instagram"
    app:btntext=""
    app:coindesc="Post a invitation"
    app:cointext="Share to Instagram"
    app:showweek="false"/>
```

In the view `InviteItemView` you can get the attibute `appIcon`, `btnText` with below code:

```
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.invite_item_view);
int refId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.invite_item_view_appicon, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
String btnText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.invite_item_view_btntext);
```

the `refId` and `btnText` is what you will get.

Add the below code to your `attrs.xml`, this is the definition of `invite_item_view`

```
<declare-styleable name="invite_item_view">
    <attr name="appicon" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="cointext" format="string"/>
    <attr name="coindesc" format="string"/>
    <attr name="btntext" format="string"/>
    <attr name="showweek" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try it first. And I have update my question.

Comment: Ok looks like I get a further solution [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). Thanks for your explanation. I seem to use your answer because it has custom attribute solution and still allowing reusable layout or custom view.

Answer (score 1):

`<inlcude />` tag is to help you reuse layout that difine in different page. One example is to define a custom ToolBar and reuse in Activities, Fragment.

There is noway you can add this custom tag like you mentioned, but instead you can straightaway declare in code behind, simply without DataBinding:

For example, with this `toolbar.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in `activity_main.xml`, you have:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

In `MainActivity.java` you can define this:

```
private TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
title.setText("Whatever you want");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is good either. But now I need a reusable component that has custom attribute as well. Will upvote it too :)